# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" while saving a file to access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to save this record in an Access database, but I encounter the following **error** when I click the save button:

```
"Data type mismatch in criteria expression" highlighting "dcProducts.ExecuteNonQuery"
```

---

***Code:***

```
   conn.Open()

    strProduct = "insert into Products_Table values('" & Val(txtProductID.Text) & _
                "',' " & txtProductName.Text & _
                "','" & cboUoM.Text & _
                "','" & txtRemarks.Text & _
                "','" & txtPrice.Text & "')"

    dcProduct = New OleDbCommand(strProduct, conn)
    dcProduct.ExecuteNonQuery()

    For i = 0 To dgvRawMaterials.RowCount - 2

        strRawMaterial = "insert into BillsofMaterials values('" & Val((dgvRawMaterials.Item(0, i).Value)) & _
                 "',' " & Val(dgvRawMaterials.Item(2, i).Value) & "')"


        dcRawMaterial = New OleDbCommand(strRawMaterial, conn)
        dcRawMaterial.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
```

Comment: Are you sure ProductID is a Text field?  You've got it surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: no it isn't actually but i have tried without it as well, still got the same error

Comment: How about checking which columns in the table are required and which allow nulls, then try inserting just the minimum field(s) to see if you still get the error.  That may help narrow it down. Also, would certainly remove quotes from around numeric field(s).